# Pandas Insert Row Subtotal in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, xlsxwriter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuuIz.png)**Target:**
I have a pandas data frame, as shown below, with multiple of the column and would like to get the subtotal for few columns and write "Total" at Placement# Name.

**DataFrame:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exmlh.png)

**My Attempt:**

```
**adsize_sales_second_table.loc["Grand Total"] = pd.Series(adsize_sales_second_table.loc
                                                             [:, ["Delivered Impressions",
                                                                  "Clicks",
                                                                  "Conversion", "Spend"]].sum(),
                                                    index=["Delivered Impressions", "Clicks", "Conversion", "Spend"]**
                                                             )
```

This is adding a row at last and can't be figuring out to fill subtotal:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrDIn.png)

**Expected Output:**
I'd have expected the output to be as followed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGZvL.png)

**See edited code:**

```
  adsize_sales_data = adsize_sales_second_table.loc[:, ["Placement# Name", "Adsize", "Delivered Impressions", "Clicks",
                                                              "CTR", "Conversion", "Conversion Rate", "Spend", "eCPA"]]


        cols = ["Delivered Impressions", "Clicks", "Conversion", "Spend"]

        adsize_sales_data['Placement# Name'] = adsize_sales_data['Placement# Name'].ffill()
        grand = adsize_sales_data[cols].sum()
        grand.loc['Placement# Name'] = 'Grand total'

        adsize_sales_data_new = adsize_sales_data.groupby('Placement# Name')[cols].sum()

        adsize_sales_data_new.index = adsize_sales_data.index.astype(str)+'____'

        adsize_sales_data = (pd.concat([adsize_sales_data.set_index('Placement# Name'), adsize_sales_data_new], keys=('a', 'b')).sort_index(level=1).reset_index())

        adsize_sales_data['Placement# Name'] = np.where(adsize_sales_data ['level_0'] == 'a', adsize_sales_data['Placement# Name'], 'Total')

        adsize_sales_data = adsize_sales_data.drop('level_0', axis=1)

        adsize_sales_data.loc[len(adsize_sales_data.index)] = grand

        print (adsize_sales_data)
```

it is now giving values error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMHqW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#specify columns to sum
cols = ["Delivered Impressions", "Clicks", "Conversion", "Spend"]
#replace NaNs by forward filling
df['Placement# Name'] = df['Placement# Name'].ffill()
#count grand total
grand = df[cols].sum()
grand.loc['Placement# Name'] = 'Grand total'
print (grand)

#get subtotal by aggregation sum 
df1 = df.groupby('Placement# Name')[cols].sum()
#change sum for correct order
df1.index = df1.index + '____'
#join to original, sort by second level of MultiIndex
df = (pd.concat([df.set_index('Placement# Name'), df1], keys=('a', 'b'))
        .sort_index(level=1)
        .reset_index())

#change values to total
df['Placement# Name'] = np.where(df['level_0'] == 'a', df['Placement# Name'], 'Total')
#remove column
df = df.drop('level_0', axis=1)
#add grand total
df.loc[len(df.index)] = grand
```

---

```
print (df)
                                      Placement# Name   Adsize          CTR  \
0   13.iab units (mobile only) + non-expanding adh...   320x50    0.0119683   
1                                               Total      NaN          NaN   
2   15.iab units (mobile only) + non-expanding adh...   320x50    0.0138741   
3   15.iab units (mobile only) + non-expanding adh...   768x90    0.0271041   
4                                               Total      NaN          NaN   
5                     18.iab units - desktop + mobile  160x600   0.00155927   
6                     18.iab units - desktop + mobile  300x250   0.00797965   
7                     18.iab units - desktop + mobile  300x600   0.00275059   
8                     18.iab units - desktop + mobile   728x90   0.00496391   
9                                               Total      NaN          NaN   
10  4.iab units (mobile only) + non-expanding adhe...   320x50    0.0141497   
11                                              Total      NaN          NaN   
12  5.iab units (mobile only) + non-expanding adhe...   320x50    0.0111654   
13  5.iab units (mobile only) + non-expanding adhe...   768x90    0.0253428   
14                                              Total      NaN          NaN   
15                     6.iab units - desktop + mobile  160x600  7.41895e-05   
16                     6.iab units - desktop + mobile  300x250     0.011838   
17                     6.iab units - desktop + mobile  300x600  0.000259538   
18                     6.iab units - desktop + mobile   728x90   0.00538178   
19                                              Total      NaN          NaN   
20                                        Grand total      NaN          NaN   

   Clicks Conversion Conversion Rate Delivered Impressions    Spend     eCPA  
0    1888          4     2.53566e-05                157750  1126.79  281.696  
1    1888          4             NaN                157750  1126.79      NaN  
2    2121         17     0.000111202                152875  1091.96  64.2332  
3     152          2     0.000356633                  5608  40.0571  20.0286  
4    2273         19             NaN                158483  1132.02      NaN  
5      37         21     0.000884993                 23729  132.204  6.29545  
6     684         58     0.000676637                 85718  477.572    8.234  
7      34         13      0.00105169                 12361  68.8684  5.29757  
8     403         80     0.000985392                 81186  452.322  5.65403  
9    1158        172             NaN                202994  1130.97      NaN  
10   3840         23     8.47511e-05                271383  1938.45  84.2804  
11   3840         23             NaN                271383  1938.45      NaN  
12   1127          4     3.96287e-05                100937  720.979  180.245  
13    183          0               0                  7221  51.5786        0  
14   1310          4             NaN                108158  772.557      NaN  
15      1          0               0                 13479  75.0973        0  
16    792          0               0                 66903  372.745        0  
17      1          0               0                  3853  21.4667        0  
18    266          0               0                 49426  275.373        0  
19   1060          0             NaN                133661  744.683      NaN  
20  11529        222             NaN           1.03243e+06  6845.46      NaN  

#if necessary write to file
df.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
```

EDIT1:

```
cols = ["Delivered Impressions", "Clicks", "Conversion", "Spend"]

df['Placement# Name'] = df['Placement# Name'].ffill()
grand = df[cols].sum()
grand.loc['Placement# Name'] = 'Grand total'
print (grand)

df1 = df.groupby('Placement# Name')[cols].sum()
df1.index = df1.index + '____'

#create empty DataFrame
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=df1.index + '__')
df = pd.concat([df.set_index('Placement# Name'), df1, df2], keys=('a', 'b', 'c')).sort_index(level=1).reset_index()

#get output by 2 conditions
m1 = df['level_0'] == 'a'
m2 = df['level_0'] == 'c'
df['Placement# Name'] = np.select([m1, m2], [df['Placement# Name'], np.nan], default='Total')
df = df.drop('level_0', axis=1)
df.loc[len(df.index)] = grand
```

---

```
print (df)
0   13.iab units (mobile only) + non-expanding adh...   320x50    0.0119683   
1                                               Total      NaN          NaN   
2                                                 NaN      NaN          NaN   
3   15.iab units (mobile only) + non-expanding adh...   320x50    0.0138741   
4   15.iab units (mobile only) + non-expanding adh...   768x90    0.0271041   
5                                               Total      NaN          NaN   
6                                                 NaN      NaN          NaN   
7                     18.iab units - desktop + mobile  160x600   0.00155927   
8                     18.iab units - desktop + mobile  300x250   0.00797965   
9                     18.iab units - desktop + mobile  300x600   0.00275059   
10                    18.iab units - desktop + mobile   728x90   0.00496391   
11                                              Total      NaN          NaN   
12                                                NaN      NaN          NaN   
13  4.iab units (mobile only) + non-expanding adhe...   320x50    0.0141497   
14                                              Total      NaN          NaN   
15                                                NaN      NaN          NaN   
16  5.iab units (mobile only) + non-expanding adhe...   320x50    0.0111654   
17  5.iab units (mobile only) + non-expanding adhe...   768x90    0.0253428   
18                                              Total      NaN          NaN   
19                                                NaN      NaN          NaN   
20                     6.iab units - desktop + mobile  160x600  7.41895e-05   
21                     6.iab units - desktop + mobile  300x250     0.011838   
22                     6.iab units - desktop + mobile  300x600  0.000259538   
23                     6.iab units - desktop + mobile   728x90   0.00538178   
24                                              Total      NaN          NaN   
25                                                NaN      NaN          NaN   
26                                        Grand total      NaN          NaN   

   Clicks Conversion Conversion Rate Delivered Impressions    Spend     eCPA  
0    1888          4     2.53566e-05                157750  1126.79  281.696  
1    1888          4             NaN                157750  1126.79      NaN  
2     NaN        NaN             NaN                   NaN      NaN      NaN  
3    2121         17     0.000111202                152875  1091.96  64.2332  
4     152          2     0.000356633                  5608  40.0571  20.0286  
5    2273         19             NaN                158483  1132.02      NaN  
6     NaN        NaN             NaN                   NaN      NaN      NaN  
7      37         21     0.000884993                 23729  132.204  6.29545  
8     684         58     0.000676637                 85718  477.572    8.234  
9      34         13      0.00105169                 12361  68.8684  5.29757  
10    403         80     0.000985392                 81186  452.322  5.65403  
11   1158        172             NaN                202994  1130.97      NaN  
12    NaN        NaN             NaN                   NaN      NaN      NaN  
13   3840         23     8.47511e-05                271383  1938.45  84.2804  
14   3840         23             NaN                271383  1938.45      NaN  
15    NaN        NaN             NaN                   NaN      NaN      NaN  
16   1127          4     3.96287e-05                100937  720.979  180.245  
17    183          0               0                  7221  51.5786        0  
18   1310          4             NaN                108158  772.557      NaN  
19    NaN        NaN             NaN                   NaN      NaN      NaN  
20      1          0               0                 13479  75.0973        0  
21    792          0               0                 66903  372.745        0  
22      1          0               0                  3853  21.4667        0  
23    266          0               0                 49426  275.373        0  
24   1060          0             NaN                133661  744.683      NaN  
25    NaN        NaN             NaN                   NaN      NaN      NaN  
26  11529        222             NaN           1.03243e+06  6845.46      NaN
```

Comment: thanks for working on this, however, it looks like bit tricky. what if the data frame looks like the attached screenshot and gets the output like on the same file. is it going to make easy to check? See edits

Comment: @abhilashmishra - I have no better solution if want use pandas, sorry. There is some problem with another dataframe? Can you explain more what is problem?

Comment: it is giving type error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'long' and 'str'"  on this line  adsize_sales_data_new.index=adsize_sales_data.index+'____'

Comment: then use `adsize_sales_data_new.index=adsize_sales_data.index.astype(str)+'____'`

Comment: @abhilashmishra - It have to be some data issue, can you send me your input file to my email? thanks.

Comment: Sent the file. The values are in data frame I just have written them into excel.

Comment: I test is by `df = pd.read_excel('test(123).xlsx')` and it working nice. Only is necessary remove grand total last row. For you it does not work?

Comment: Yes, it's not working, the error is attached to edits.

Comment: If use `df = pd.read_excel('test(123).xlsx')` and it does not work, maybe use some old version of pandas? solution was tested in `pandas 0.22.0`

Comment: changed the version, It starts running.  which is rectified and the code is running now. However, the output is not like as expected. I have sent you the out coming.

Comment: @abhilashmishra - so there is always row grand total in input data?

Comment: No, it's not like that.. I can remove it.

Comment: @abhilashmishra - So if remove it all will working nice ;)

Comment: No it's not like that, I can remove it. I'm just adding it in my code. That's why it's coming

Comment: @abhilashmishra - I understand. There is problem you can add grand total after my code - my way `df.loc[len(df.index)] = grand` or use your solution else get Total for `Grand total` too.

Comment: Got it.Thanks a million

Comment: The only thing I wish to know, any way to insert blank row after each Total and before grand total.

Comment: Not so easy, but please give me some time.